# How to remove blank lines from a C# List<string>?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a routine in C# that sorts a list added to a Multi-Line text box.  Once that is done, there is an option to remove all blank lines.  Can someone tell me how I would go about doing this?  here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work at all when I select the box and click sort:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ',',' ',':','|','\n' };
    List<string> sortBox1 = new List<string>(textBox2.Text.Split(delimiterChars));

    if (checkBox3.Checked) //REMOVE BLANK LINES FROM LIST
    {
        sortBox1.RemoveAll(item => item == "\r\n");
    }

    textBox3.Text = string.Join("\r\n", sortBox1);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're splitting the string on `'\n'`, `sortBox1` won't contain a string containing `\n`. I would just use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), though:

```
sortBox1.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to sort the lines:

```
sortBox1.Sort();
```

A blank line is not `"\r\n"`, that is a line break. Blank lines are empty strings:

```
sortBox1.RemoveAll(item => item.Length == 0);
```

You can also remove the blank lines when splitting the string:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    char[] delimiterChars = { ',',' ',':','|','\n' };

    StringSplitOptions options;
    if (checkBox3.Checked) {
        options = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
    } else {
        options = StringSplitOptions.None;
    }

    List<string> sortBox1 = new List<string>(textBox2.Text.Split(delimiterChars, options));
    sortBox1.Sort();
    textBox3.Text = string.Join("\r\n", sortBox1);
}
```